# How to make a stacked flexslider slideshow carousel

Tags: javascript

I would like two ad blocks showing the same randomized content, but without duplicates.

I could just use two different blocks, with different flexslider options, (both starting on different images and moves by two), but that only works with even number images and can not be randomized.

Right now, I'm trying to make a carousel showing two images, and trying to restrict the container to a size that they form two layers. The problem: flexslider still moves on to white space, as if it was still one long layer.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it to work, but using [views slideshow](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_slideshow). I just clicked "View Action Advanced Options" in the action setting, setting it to two slides. I also renamed the flexslider library and made sure that I downloaded the full version of cycle. And that's it!